# REST : Post endpoint with url query parameter and body content

Tags: git, rest

I am creating a webhook endpoint for different git servers.
The webhook url will be configured in the git server and will be used to send POST request with a body containing metadata about an event (like the information about a commit after a commit is pushed).
The content of the POST request is different from a server to another : the attributes and the values are git provider specific.

I want to use the same endpoint url if it is possible with a query parameter to distinguish which git provider I am dealing with.
My endpoint would be something like this :

```
/repositories/commits?type={git_provider}
```

An examples for the urls to be configured in gitlab or Atlassian stash are :

```
/repositories/commits?type=stash
/repositories/commits?type=gitlabs
```

The problem is that the content of POST request's body will be different depending on the value of type . Is it doable in such manner? or should I create differents endpoints for each type, in which case I will have multiple endpoints each processing a different Post's body depending on git type.

```
/stash/repositories/commits
/gitlabs/repositories/commits
```

**Using a single endpoint with a query parameter**

**Pro:**

- Respecting the same hierarchy used in other endpoint

**Cons:**

- Depending on the value of the query parameter there will be different manner of reading the body of the request because of the naming/values of the attributes .

**Using a single endpoint with a query parameter**

**Pro:**

- Each endpoint will be simple and and will be processing a fixed Post body

**Con:**

- the hierarchy of the new endpoints will be not respecting the same hierarchy  of the existing endpoints  .

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. All URL suggestions in the question would work - what should be done depends on personal preference or fitting it into an existing scheme that isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'll edit the question to add more details

Comment: Reading the edit, I'd still say this is opinion-based. You have the basic problem to send different POST-bodies to different URLs. It doesn't matter if the difference in the URL is before or after the `?` - it is different. Who should care about it in your question? Who would be affected by that decision?

Comment: I believe having differents endpoint is more clean but it is breaking the hierarchy and the semantic of the api because I have to add the type of git server somewhere in the url

Comment: Going from the URL requested to the code to process the request is called "routing", and usually this is not a 1:1 mapping anymore (i.e. the URL directly maps to the file with the code to execute). You should probably establish a routing layer to be able to create meaningful URLs for the outside world that do not dictate how to call stuff inside your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have never worked with the git APIs, I expect there will be a lot of overlapping properties with the different git providers. Each provider might use different terminology or naming schemes, but the actual data itself would be the same. As a result, I would recommend using a single resource, with the query string differentiating which provider would be used.

Name your API properties in a generic manner that is not tied too closely to any particular provider. Then you would "translate" the API property name into the provider-specific property. This would hide the various provider implementations from the API consumer, so if you add a new provider or change them, your API would not change.